# Move all sent email from gmail to outlook web access

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, outlook-web-access

Due to a re-organization at my working place, I have to change my address and shift my e-mail account from my gmail to outlook web access (owa).

Since I don't want to lose my old contacs and e-mails, I would like to know if and how I can move all the sent e-mails from gmail to owa.

This might help me to make this transition less traumatic.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you done any research? Search Google for "export gmail" and there are lots of results.

Comment: I have to say that I agree with @CharlieRB. We are a very helpful bunch, but less inclined to help someone who seemingly hasn't made the effort to find the answer themselves beforehand.

Comment: If there is something unusual about your setup that would prevent or complicate following the readily available instructions, or if there is something specific in the instructions you don't understand, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move your existing mail (not limited to sent email, by the way) using Office365's built in migration service.

What you're looking for is IMAP migration, as gmail supports IMAP you can add your account into Outlook web access and have all your mail imported.

There are lots of guides on how to achieve this. But I would *strongly suggest* you ask your IT staff to do this for all users using the migration tools provided by Microsoft for exactly this scenario.

If you want to do this on your own, star with these steps:

---

Make sure you have configured Gmail to allow IMAP connections (found under `Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP`)

Create a connection to another account

Before you connect to download mail from another email account, you may need to turn on POP or IMAP access from the other account. For more information, see Turn on POP or IMAP access to connect to another account.

1. In Outlook Web App, click Settings Settings icon > Options > Account > Connected accounts.
2. Click New `+`.
3. In the New Account Connection dialog box, type the email address and
   password of the account you want to connect to, and then click Next.
4. If you see the message that your accounts are connected, click
   Finish. Messages sent to your connected account will appear in your
   Inbox.
5. If you see the message that Outlook Web App couldn’t connect to the
   server for your other account, click Back and
   make sure that you entered the correct email address and password
   for your other account.

---

Source and further info can be found in [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-another-email-account-174da61d-2c8d-4b62-bf4f-8c1dd06a97cf) and [this How-to-guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568114.aspx). Both articles are from Microsoft and the second one even has videos that show you how it's done

Comment: You can also look at using Outlook desktop client (if you have Office 2013) as the proxy. Add both Gmail and Exchange account to Outlook. Then it is a matter of moving the Gmail emails to Exchange by drag-n-drop.